# Get user and fill all permissions

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, slick, slick-3.0, silhouette

I am new to Scala and even what I am trying to achieve is too simple with Java, i feel confused with Scala.

What I want is to get a `User` and then fill his `Permission` using another query and based to his `Role` and his individual `Permissions`.

Until know I have the following code:

```
/**
* Finds a user by its loginInfo.
*
* @param loginInfo The loginInfo of the user to find.
* @return The found user or None if no user for the given login info could be found.
*/
def find(loginInfo: LoginInfo): Future[Option[models.admin.User]] = {

val userQuery = for {
  dbLoginInfo <- loginInfoQuery(loginInfo)
  dbUserLoginInfo <- Userlogininfo.filter(_.logininfoid === dbLoginInfo.id)
  dbUser <- User.filter(_.userid === dbUserLoginInfo.userid)
  user <- dbUser match {
    case u =>
      val permissionQuery = for {
        dbUserPermission <- Userpermission.filter(_.userid === u.userid)
        dbPermission <- Permission.filter(_.id === dbUserPermission.permissionid)
      } yield dbPermission

      val rolePermissionQuery = for {
        dbUserRole <- Userrole.filter(_.userid === u.userid)
        dbRole <- Role.filter(_.id === dbUserRole.roleid)
        dbRolePermission <- Rolepermission.filter(_.roleid === dbRole.id)
        dbPermission <- Permission.filter(_.id === dbRolePermission.permissionid)
      } yield dbPermission

      val unionPermissionQuery = permissionQuery union rolePermissionQuery

      db.run(unionPermissionQuery.result).map(_.map(_.name).toList).map { permission =>

        models.admin.User(
          UUID.fromString(u.userid.toString),
          u.firstname.toString,
          u.lastname.toString,
          u.jobtitle.toString,
          loginInfo,
          u.email.toString,
          false,
          Some(permission),
          false)
      }
    case None => None
  }
} yield user

db.run(userQuery.result.headOption)

}
```

I got the following errors:

```
pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
[error]  found   : None.type
[error]  required: UserDAOImpl.this.User
[error]         case None => None
[error]              ^
[error] play/modules/admin/app/models/daos/impl/UserDAOImpl.scala:36: value map is not a member of Object
[error]       user <- dbUser match {
[error]                      ^
[error] play/modules/admin/app/models/daos/impl/UserDAOImpl.scala:34: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : UserDAOImpl.this.Userlogininfo => slick.lifted.Query[Nothing,Nothing,Seq]
[error]  required: UserDAOImpl.this.Userlogininfo => slick.lifted.Query[Nothing,T,Seq]
[error]       dbUserLoginInfo <- Userlogininfo.filter(_.logininfoid === dbLoginInfo.id)
[error]                       ^
[error] play/modules/admin/app/models/daos/impl/UserDAOImpl.scala:33: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : UserDAOImpl.this.Logininfo => slick.lifted.Query[Nothing,Nothing,Seq]
[error]  required: UserDAOImpl.this.Logininfo => slick.lifted.Query[Nothing,T,Seq]
[error]       dbLoginInfo <- loginInfoQuery(loginInfo)
[error]                   ^
[error] play/modules/admin/app/models/daos/impl/UserDAOImpl.scala:69: value headOption is not a member of UserDAOImpl.this.driver.DriverAction[Seq[Nothing],UserDAOImpl.this.driver.api.NoStream,slick.dbio.Effect.Read]
[error]     db.run(userQuery.result.headOption)
[error]                             ^
[error] 5 errors found
```

Comment: `case u =>` will match anything. If you want to modify Option if it's `Some` and leave it `None` otherways you can use `map` . I don't really know how to help with other things as I don't know slick but maybe try to annotate types you expect and let compiler tell you where you fail.

Comment: The error messages you are getting, if you read them closely, are already telling you what your problems are. Is there a particular error message you're having difficulty interpreting...?

Comment: It will be easier to debug if you can give the schemas of your tables and the methods ..

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you work with a for-comprehension with a `yield` you have to understand that you a working with some sort of "wrapped" value (monad). It can be a `Future`, a `List`, an `Option`, or anything else that is monadic.

So the pattern is kind of like this:

```
for {
  someValue <- someWrappedValue()
  someOtherValue <- someWrappedOtherValue(someValue)
} yield someOtherValue
```

If you are working with `Future`, then you can use these rules:

- Everything to the right of a `<-` must be a `Future`
- Everything to the left of a `<-` is the "unwrapped" value
- The value of the entire for-comprehension will be whatever is on the `yield` wrapped in a `Future`

The rules are the same for `List`, `Option`, etc. But you cannot mix and match within the same for-comprehension.

One of the errors hints that the result of your `match` statement is of type `Object`, which means scala couldn't figure out a common type for all the cases in the match. You want all of the cases to produce a `Future` (since that's what we're working with in this for-comprehension).

My guess, you need to replace:

```
case None => None
```

with:

```
case None => Future.successful(None)
```

But it's hard to know for sure without more info.

Regarding it being simpler in Java: Not exactly. What makes it a bit more complex is not the language, but the fact that a lot of the methods are asynchronous. If you were to do it synchronously in scala, it would be just as simple as java, if not more. But then you would be blocking a thread every time you are waiting for results, which is the case with java (assuming synchronous calls).